# Auto update Git Script

Tags: git, bash

I want to write a script that, after a git pull request, copies the pulled files to a different location.

I understand that I need to put the request in one of the hook files, either `post-pull`, `post-merge` or `post-update`.

I am however not sure how I will see which files are newly added with the pull and how to copy those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post-update` is executed after a push was done on the remote repository where you pushed to. `post-pull` does not exist. What you want is `post-merge` if you use `pull` with `merge`, or `post-rewrite` if you use `pull` with `rebase`. But be aware that those hooks are not only called on `pull`, but on any `merge`, respectively on any rewriting commit like `git commit --amend` and so on. So you might want to add some additional condition as to when to execute your additional actions.

To find the changed files in the `post-merge` hook, you need to use normal Git commands, like `git diff master@{1} master --name-status` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

А simple way is to create an alias for your git commands, which calls a wrapper script. The wrapper script will perform the git command and then use the specified parameters e.g. the filename for the copy operation.